# Cannot import AcroForms from jsdpf

Tags: node.js, jspdf

I am following the official examples and documentation of jspdf (version 2.5.1).

I managed to run this snippet in Vue3 in order to generate a PDF that also includes forms that can be edited in the PDF. So far, it is the only library I have found that does support them, eventhough it is a real pain to work with (originally I wanted to use Python weasyprint, but it does render  tags only as blocks that cannot be edited and saved in the PDF).

I want to generate the PDF now on the server, running TypeScript in NodeJS v20.5.1. However, I receive an import error or type error when I add the perfectly running code from the Vue app. I am beyond confusion.

---

Perfectly running in Vue:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

function downloadPdf() {
  const { TextField } = jsPDF.AcroForm;

  const doc = new jsPDF({
    orientation: "portrait",
    unit: "mm",
    format: "a4"
  });

  doc.setFontSize(16);
  doc.text("Header", 20, 20);

  const field = new TextField();
  field.Rect = [ coords.x, coords.y-height, width, height ];
  field.defaultValue = value;
  field.fieldName = "form-name";
  doc.addField(field);
  doc.save("test.pdf");
}
</script>

<template>
  <buttonn @click="downloadPdf">Download PDF</button>
</template>
```

Same code in NodeJS:

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

function downloadPdf() {
  const { TextField } = jsPDF.AcroForm;

  const doc = new jsPDF({
    orientation: "portrait",
    unit: "mm",
    format: "a4"
  });

  doc.setFontSize(16);
  doc.text("Header", 20, 20);

  const field = new TextField();
  field.Rect = [ coords.x, coords.y-height, width, height ];
  field.defaultValue = value;
  field.fieldName = "form-name";
  doc.addField(field);
  doc.save("test.pdf");
}
```

I get this error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'AcroForm' does not exist on type 'typeof jsPDF'.
    const { TextField } = jsPDF.AcroForm;
```

However, when I print `console.log(jsPDF)` I see such a field and all the documented entities like `AcroFormTextField`.

```
[Function: I] {
  API: {
    events: [/* ... */],
    addField: [Function (anonymous)],
    /* ... */
    AcroFormTextField: [Function: gt],
    AcroForm: {
      /* ... */
      TextField: [Function: gt]
    },
    /* ... */   
  },
  version: '2.5.1',
  AcroForm: {
    /* ... */
    FormField: [Function: gt],
  }
}
```

edit: accessing `jsPDF.AcroForm`, `jsPDF.AcroFormTextField` or `jsPDF.TextField` does result in an error as well (and so does `jsPDF.API.AcroForm` and so on).

```
error TS2339: Property 'AcroForm' does not exist on type 'typeof jsPDF'.
    console.log(jsPDF.AcroForm);
```

What do I miss? Why does it work with Vue and not in Node?

PS: is there a similar library (can be Python or JavaScript) for PDF generation that supports form elements inside the PDF? I want to import the filled PDF in the next step of the API, thus form fields are essential.

Comment: I was more astonished about how only few more advanced generators exist out there in the open-source world. Afterall, PDF is the most popular document format for decades. Yet, it is quite archaic to tell by the pixel where which element has to go. Only HTML+CSS generator I found was Python weasyprint. However, no forms :( In such a case I can simply use the print functionality of the browser itself.

Answer (score 1):

The jsPDF library is great but documentation is often not easy to understand.
Currently there is several documentation but these one are official, unfortunately it is not the one Google return as first result for "jspdf documentation" request:

- Library Reference: https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html
- Show Case: http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/index.html

The showcase can help you to find how to organise your code but it is not accurate for class, properties or method, you must use the library reference.

I am working with Angular and i succeed to create a form field with this kind of code. Give it a try.

```
import jsPDF, {
  AcroFormTextField
} from 'jspdf';

const pdfFile = new jsPDF();

const field = new AcroFormTextField();
field.fieldName = "my_field";
field.x = 100;
field.width = 200;
field.y = 100;
field.height = 50;

pdfFile.addField(field);
```